# Source / Alias not Permanent in Mac .bashrc

Tags: bash, macos, symlink

I have a `.sources` symlink pointing to a directory with files I wish to source when Terminal is opened.

In my `.bashrc` file, which is sourced from `~/.bash_profile`, I have the following code

```
sourcesDir=$HOME/.sources
ls -B $sourcesDir | while read filename; do
  echo "source $sourcesDir/$filename"
  source $sourcesDir/$filename
done
```

When I start Terminal, I get the following output

```
source /Users/merlinpatterson/.sources/bash_aliases
source /Users/merlinpatterson/.sources/git_completion.bash
source /Users/merlinpatterson/.sources/git_prompt.sh
source /Users/merlinpatterson/.sources/meteor.sh
```

However, when I run `alias`, none of the aliases show up. Any variables exported are blank. And `__git_ps1` is not found.

If I run the above commands after starting the Terminal, everything works, so the files themselves are fine.

Why are the results of `source` not staying around in the Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop runs in a subshell, not your current shell. Use instead

```
for filename in "$sourcesDir"/*; do
    source "$filename"
done
```